# Get elements that are not present in each of the arrays

Tags: java

I have two int Arrays:

> int[] first = new int[]{1, 4, 5};
>
> int[] second = new int[]{9, 7, 1, 5, 5};

I need to get elements that are not present in each of the arrays.
Result: 9, 7, 4

I can get this result as follows:

> ```
>     int[] first = new int[]{1, 4, 5};
>     int[] second = new int[]{9, 7, 1, 5, 5};
>
>     Set<Integer> firstSet = Arrays.stream(first).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());
>     Set<Integer> secondSet = Arrays.stream(second).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());
>
>     Set<Integer> result = new HashSet<>();
>
>     Arrays.stream(first).forEach(v -> {
>         if (!secondSet.contains(v)) {
>             result.add(v);
>         }
>     });
>     Arrays.stream(second).forEach(v -> {
>         if (!firstSet.contains(v)) {
>             result.add(v);
>         }
>     });
>
>     result.forEach(System.out::println);
> ```

**How to get this result more correctly?**

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] first = new int[] { 1, 4, 5 };
        int[] second = new int[] { 9, 7, 1, 5, 5 };
        Set<Integer> firstSet = Arrays.stream(first).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());
        Set<Integer> secondSet = Arrays.stream(second).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());
        Set<Integer> firstSetCopy = new HashSet<>(firstSet);

        firstSet.removeAll(secondSet);
        secondSet.removeAll(firstSetCopy);

        Set<Integer> result = new HashSet<>();
        result.addAll(firstSet);
        result.addAll(secondSet);

        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[4, 7, 9]
```